# What's this exactly in laptops?

Tags: laptop, sony-vaio

I opened 2 laptops today and both of them had something like this in them. I posted larger pic so you know it's not the GPU or CPU, it's a 3rd piece of hardware which gets so hot too as i touched it but it doesn't have any thermal paste on it. can anyone identify this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmm... where is the GPU on your photo?

Comment: there are 2 heatsinks in the photo as you can see, one is white and one is orange, those are on CPU and GPU

Comment: on one of them is written i5 CPU and other one is written ATI which is GPU

Comment: Looking up the part number shows me a bunch of vendors but none of them so far have had the product name listed. The manufacturer is Intel, though.

Comment: I would rate up your answers but someone decided to down vote my question so my total points aren't enough to up vote you guys, thanks anyway.

Comment: Closing - Out of scope, we don't do "identify this thing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [googling](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=bd82hm55) for the code on that parts it shows to be the chipset.

http://eu.mouser.com/new/Intel/intel-hm55-express-chipset/

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be the [Intel HM55 Express Chipset](http://ark.intel.com/products/43183/Mobile-Intel-HM55-Express-Chipset), which provided GPU functionality next to other I/O.

If you enter the product number into Google, you will find similar images to yours. This seems to be a [related product](https://www.amazon.ca/INTEL-BD82HM65-SLJ4P-Graphic-Processor/dp/B00LBUZO5Y) (slightly different product number).

Comment: so it's different from the integrated GPU inside a core i series CPU?

Comment: Yes, it is a different GPU than the on-processor GPU.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, slightly incorrect.  It is not a another GPU, but provides I/O for a number of different things, including graphics.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Better now?

Comment: @PatrickHofman, yes +1

Comment: It would be better to say that the chipset is connected to the integrated GPU.  It would even be better if you provided a diagram of how the chipset itself interacts with the CPU.  The chipset itself does not provide GPU functionality.